# How to replace window.getSelection().toString() data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have gotten the window.getSelection()  data that the user has selected. How to replace or update the current selected data?
I want to replace currently selected data with what is in the variable

```
$scope.mouseUpEvent = function() {

    $scope.selectedText =  $scope.getSelectionText();
   // do i do the function here to replace

}; 

$scope.getSelectionText = function(){

// Predefine select and range
    var sel, range;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
           var range = sel.getRangeAt(0),
            content = range.cloneContents();
     }
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-mouseup="mouseUpEvent()"   ng-keyup="keyUpEvent()" contenteditable >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace an element in javascript you first need to create the element using document.createElement and than you need to insert the created element into the range that you have predefiened.

```
 createEl= document.createElement(div);
 range.insertNode(createEl);
```